# jQuery input box automatically add DOT into Currency format and only allow numeric

Tags: jquery, number-formatting

I have input box with condition to allow only numeric. While adding numeric automatically add DOTs as currency format like following.

```
100 = 100
1000 = 1.000
10000 = 10.000
1000000 = 100.000
1000000 = 1.000.000


<input type="text" class="form-control" name="number_one" id="number_one" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" onkeyup="return CurrencyFormat(this.value)">
```

Can anyone please guide me how to call function value.

I found following useful but **How to modify this function to automatically to add Dots** into input box value **and condition to only allow numbers**.

```
function getNumberWithCommas(number) {
    return number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check following snippet demo.

```js
$('input.numberformat').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
    .replace(/\D/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")
    ;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="numberformat">
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but to have the function called on the element value you can have set `onchange` attribute, but if you already have a function that handle `onchange` and want to integrate it with this function please add to your question too and I will amend my answer accordingly.

```js
function CurrencyFormat(el) {
    let val = el.value.split('.').join('');
    el.value = val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="number_one" id="number_one" onkeypress="CurrencyFormat(this)" >
```

Comment: For allowing only number I am using following way
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="number_one" id="number_one" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" onkeyup="return CurrencyFormat(this.value)">

Comment: @VipulGhetiya, its working as a snippet, not sure what not working, will check the number value in minutes.

Comment: Thanks ... I modified your function  little bit like this http://prntscr.com/rl3i2n

We are close enough

Comment: Thanks for your snippet above. Instead of "OnChange" event it makes change only when we go to next input field. Can you please modify to OnKeyPress or something. By doing that we can check live updates of values

Comment: Ok sure, will amend it now